# MySQL: Count event attendance based on event type

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have three tables set up to track attendance at events.  The tables are as follows:

```
Users
--------
rid
name

Events
--------
eid
name
type (either 0 or 1)

Attendance
--------
rid
eid
```

I'm trying to return all of the users and print out a count of the amount of events they've attended broken into the amount for type 1 and type 0.

I can successfully return one or the other but not a combination of both with the following statement:

```
SELECT users.name, COUNT(type) as typeCount FROM attendance, events, users
WHERE users.rid=attendance.rid && events.eid=attendance.eid && type=1 GROUP BY users.rid
```

Which returns

```
╔══════╦══════════════╗
║ name ║  typeCount   ║ 
╠══════╬══════════════╣
║ John ║      5       ║
╠══════╬══════════════╣
║ Jack ║      3       ║
╚══════╩══════════════╝
```

But I would like it to return

```
╔══════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ name ║  type0Count  ║ type1Count  ║
╠══════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ John ║      2       ║      5      ║
╠══════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Jack ║      7       ║      3      ║
╚══════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CASE...WHEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) inside the `COUNT` function to count specific values in a column.

```
SELECT
    Users.rid,
    Users.Name,
    COUNT(CASE Events.type WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS type0Count,
    COUNT(CASE Events.type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS type1Count
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Attendance ON Users.rid = Attendance.rid
INNER JOIN Events ON Attendance.eid = Events.eid
GROUP BY Users.rid, Users.Name
```

You can also use `IF` or `NULLIF` as well.

Comment: add `END` in the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take out the type from filter

```
SELECT users.name,type, COUNT(type) as typeCount 
FROM attendance, events, users
WHERE
users.rid=attendance.rid 
&& events.eid=attendance.eid 
GROUP BY users.rid,type
```

or

```
SELECT users.name, 
CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN COUNT(1) AS type0Count END,
CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN COUNT(1) AS type1Count END 
FROM attendance, events, users
WHERE users.rid=attendance.rid 
&& 
events.eid=attendance.eid
GROUP BY users.rid
```